# The NART as a measure of premorbid IQ in serious mental illness

Tags: abnormal-psychology, intelligence, reading

How reliable is [National Adult Reading Test](http://www.academia.edu/2515150/National_Adult_Reading_Test_NART_test_manual_Part_1) in estimating premorbid IQ in schizophrenia?

Is it compromised if the difference between current IQ and the NART is a standard deviation or more?